# How to easily read AnyObject stored in dictionaries?

Tags: swift, dictionary, anyobject

I have a dictionary that stores strings and integers. This dictionary's type is `[String:AnyObject]`.

```
var person: [String:AnyObject] = ["occupation": "teacher", "age": 1]
```

I read this dictionary by this way:

```
occupationLabel.text = person["occupation"] as! String
let newAge = person["age"] as! Int + 1
```

It's inconvenient. How can I use this dictionary by the following way?

```
occupationLabel.text = person["occupation"]
let newAge = person["age"] + 1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You threw away static typing of the dictionary values when you made this a `[String:AnyObject]`. What you are doing, casting each value to what you know it to be, is correct.

The *real* solution, of course, is to have a Person *type* with `occupation` and `age` *properties*!

```
struct Person {
    var occupation:String
    var age:Int
}
```

Now each property has an inherent type and you don't need to cast.